# Open Modelica custom boolean oscillator class simulation error

Tags: openmodelica

I am getting error with a simple variable frequency oscillator.
It has a boolean output and a variable input period.

```
class VarBoolPulse
  extends Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.partialBooleanSource;
  
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.BooleanOutput y;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput u;

protected
  Modelica.SIunits.Time start "Start time of current period";
  
initial algorithm
  start := time;
  
equation
  when sample(start, u) then
    start = time;
  end when;
  y = not(time >= start and time < start + u * 0.5);

end VarBoolPulse;
```

Model check is passed ok as it contains 2 equations and 2 variables and the syntax is fine.
But when I try to run simulation it spits a plenty of errors:

```
Translation Error
[/var/lib/jenkins3/ws/LINUX_BUILDS/tmp.build/openmodelica-1.21.0~2-g0bc3d29/OMCompiler/Compiler/BackEnd/BackendDAETransform.mo: 332:7-332:48]: Internal error BackendDAETransform.analyseStrongComponentBlock failed (Purely discrete algebraic loops cannot be solved by iterative processes. Try to break them open using the delay() operator.)
$whenCondition1
start
when $whenCondition1 then
  start := time;
end when;
$whenCondition1 = sample(1, start, u)

[9] 15:56:07 Translation Error
[/var/lib/jenkins3/ws/LINUX_BUILDS/tmp.build/openmodelica-1.21.0~2-g0bc3d29/OMCompiler/Compiler/BackEnd/BackendDAETransform.mo: 342:7-342:48]: Internal error BackendDAETransform.analyseStrongComponentBlock failed
variables:
  $whenCondition1
  start
equations:
  when $whenCondition1 then
  start := time;
end when;
  $whenCondition1 = sample(1, start, u)

[10] 15:56:07 Translation Error
[/var/lib/jenkins3/ws/LINUX_BUILDS/tmp.build/openmodelica-1.21.0~2-g0bc3d29/OMCompiler/Compiler/BackEnd/BackendDAETransform.mo: 346:7-346:90]: Internal error function analyseStrongComponentBlock failed

[11] 15:56:07 Translation Error
[/var/lib/jenkins3/ws/LINUX_BUILDS/tmp.build/openmodelica-1.21.0~2-g0bc3d29/OMCompiler/Compiler/BackEnd/BackendDAETransform.mo: 196:5-196:89]: Internal error function analyseStrongComponentScalar failed

[12] 15:56:07 Translation Error
[/var/lib/jenkins3/ws/LINUX_BUILDS/tmp.build/openmodelica-1.21.0~2-g0bc3d29/OMCompiler/Compiler/BackEnd/BackendDAETransform.mo: 107:7-107:113]: Internal error function strongComponentsScalar failed (sorting strong components)

[13] 15:56:07 Translation Error
[/var/lib/jenkins3/ws/LINUX_BUILDS/tmp.build/openmodelica-1.21.0~2-g0bc3d29/OMCompiler/Compiler/BackEnd/BackendDAEUtil.mo: 7953:5-7953:89]: Internal error Transformation module sort components failed
```

I am new to OpenModelica so I have not idea what is going on here.

Comment: I ran a few tests using sample(start,u) and this does not appear to be handled well by Dymola (this could be due to the Modelica Specification not sure). I would recommend not using sample().  I will have a look again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
model VarBoolPulse
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.BooleanOutput y(start=true);
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput u(start=0.1,min=1e-12);

protected 
  Real lastTrigger(fixed=false);
initial equation 
  lastTrigger =  time;

equation 

when time >= pre(lastTrigger) + u/2 then
    lastTrigger = time;
    y = not pre(y);
end when;

end VarBoolPulse;
```

I did not use units so the solution was compatible with Modelica 3.2.3 as I am using Modelica 4.0 which uses different units. Note that **u** must be strictly positive.